# Taking user back to specific textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a little routine that checks for the time input... ie if a user enters "8", it will change this to 08:00 etc etc... works great.

Now I thought I'll be smart and make sure that the user enters a max of 4 number and if not, a msgbox pops up. so far easy enough but how on earth do I take him back to the textbox so he can correct his entry ? I tried .Setfocus but nothing happens ?? any ideas ?

```
Private Sub ZB_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
   If Len(ZB) = 2 Then
    ZB = ZB & ":00"
   ElseIf Len(ZB) = 1 Then
    ZB = "0" & ZB & ":00"
   ElseIf Len(ZB) = 4 Then
    ZB = Left(ZB, 2) & ":" & Right(ZB, 2)
   ElseIf Len(ZB) = 3 Then
    ZB = Left(ZB, 1) & ":" & Right(ZB, 2)
   ElseIf Len(ZB) > 4 Then
    MsgBox "What you trying to say ???"
    ZB.SetFocus
   Else
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `ZB.Value = vbNullString`?  I assume you have not inadvertently allowed for the form to close -- it is still *shown*, right?

Comment: You can set the `MaxLength` property of textbox to 4.

Comment: Just read the answer to my Question re limiting the lenght. SUPER. Thank you. thumbs up for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Santosh's suggestion is great for limiting the characters allowed in the TextBox.  That alone may resolve this problem. But here is an answer for others who may not be able to use a character limit as readily as you can in this example.

To return focus to the Textbox `ZB`, do this:

```
    Cancel = True
    ZB.Value = vbNullString
    ZB.SetFocus
```

The `Cancel = True` is the part you're missing. This essentially cancels out the `Exit` event, then I force the TextBox value to be blank, and then `.SetFocus`.

Comment: I´m all ears re the limiting of charaters. sounds like a good idea. I´m new to VBA and it probably shows in my thinking, thus any suggestions are always welcome.